# asynchronous map in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, node.js, coffeescript

Is there an elegant way to asynchronously map an object or array in coffeescript? (Or javascript.)

Imagine I have some things in an object:

```
things = 
  x: 
    ...
  y:
    ...
  z:
    ...

thingCount = 3
```

I want to create a method that will process each of these things and return the processed object. The process has to make an asynchronous call to fetch some info about each thing.
At first I tried just to loop through the properties like so:

```
processThings = (callback) ->

  processedThings = {}
  count = 0

  for key,val in things

    asyncJob key,val (err,result) ->

      if err
        callback error
      else
        # PROBLEM: key has the incorrect value here
        processedThings[key] = result      
        count += 1
        if count == thingCount
          callback null,processedThings
```

The problem is that the value of key changes in the loop. So my solution is to create a sub-function so that the key variable is contained within its closure:

```
processThings = (callback) ->

  processedThings = {}
  count = 0

  processThing = (key,val) ->

    asyncJob key,val (err,result) ->

      if err
        callback error
      else
        processedThings[key] = result      
        count += 1
        if count == thingCount
          callback null,processedThings

  processThing key,val for key,val of things
```

But boy howdy that sure is *fugly*. Is there a preferred pattern for this?

Comment: use a [map utility](https://github.com/Raynos/after.js/blob/master/src/after.js#L64)

Comment: "after" looks like a good library Raynos - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CoffeeScript covers this with the `do` keyword, described at the end of [Loops and Comprehensions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.
>
> ```
> for filename in list
>   do (filename) ->
>     fs.readFile filename, (err, contents) ->
>       compile filename, contents.toString()
> ```

It can be applied to your code as:

```
processThings = (callback) ->

  processedThings = {}
  count = 0

  for key,val in things

    # add this to close over `key`
    do (key) ->

      asyncJob key,val (err,result) ->

        if err
          callback error
        else
          processedThings[key] = result      
          count += 1
          if count == thingCount
            callback null,processedThings
```

Comment: beautiful, thanks Jonathan! this is a slippery part of javascript.